# how can I use TermDocumentMatrix for persian text in R?

Tags: r, persian, term-document-matrix

I want to view term frequencies in documents, my documents contain Persian text. I used R as follows:

```
keycorpus <- Corpus(DirSource("E:\\Sample\\farsi texts"))
tm.matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(keycorpus)
View(as.matrix(tm.matrix))
```

Although this code is OK for english texts, unfortunately it does not work on Persian texts. How can I do this?

Comment: PLease add the error and if you don't mind a portion of the farsi text.

Comment: What's the encoding of your Farsi tests?

Comment: The encoding is UTF-8 . There is no error, but output of termdocumentmatrix in this case is just contains numbers and punctuation and the Persian terms are neglected.

Answer (score 1):

suppose that you have a text file named 1.txt
then:

```
 Sys.setlocale(locale = "Persian",category = "LC_ALL")
 setwd("E:\\Sample\\farsi_texts")
 text<-readLines("1.txt",encoding = "windows-1256")
 keycorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
 tm.matrix <- TermDocumentMatrix(keycorpus)
 View(as.matrix(tm.matrix))
```

it shows each word repetition in each line
you can use this code to aggregate:

`tm.iteration<-as.data.frame(apply(tm.matrix,1 ,sum))
 View(as.matrix(tm.iteration))`